# Can I play a audio version of salat out loud and repeat after it if I don't know how to pray?

Tags: salat

I was muslim my whole life, but I just recently realised that I am not a good muslim. Please guide me how to pray.

Comment: Why not ask somebody teach you or advise you on case there are only simple mistakes? I don't think that playing an audio is bad, but I have - depending on you knowledge base--doubts that it won't be helpful enough.